# Port Java6 along with application

Tags: java, macos

I have a Java desktop application for Mac, and we are porting Java along with the application. The issue, is that the Java we are using is strictly `Java6` and not `Java7` (Because Java7 does not have `-d32` mode).

So I downloaded Java6 jdk from the apple developer [site](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) and have bundled it in the package. And it all works well. But when I try running on other Mac's, then it throws the following error:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
$ ./java -version
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libjli.jnilib
Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/./java
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309856/java-6-on-mac-os-x-10-7-5), it tries searching for the respective directory at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` and not in the folder I ported along. How can I solve this issue?

How should I port Java6 along with the application.

Secondly, the `Java6` I have used is jdk as I could not find the Jre of Java6. It will be appreciated if someone can provide or share Jre6.

Comment: Why does your program need `-d32` mode? For a Java program it does not matter if it's running on a 32-bit or 64-bit OS. If there are problems running your program on Java 7, I'd suggest fixing those, instead of forcing users to use an outdated version of Java.

Comment: That is because I need to make native calls to `Canon` sdk which is in 32-bit only. And we cannot make 32-bit calls from 64-bit VM @Jesper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Apple licensing even allow their JRE to be redistributed with a third-party app?

I think you are making things harder than they need to be.  If a user does not have Java 6 installed (possible in OS X 10.7 and 10.8), the Mac OS will automatically prompt the user to download and install it the first time a Java application tries to run.  It will then automatically continue launching your app once it's installed.

Just make sure you are bundling your app appropriately for Java 6 (e.g., using the old Mac Jar Bundler app or manually creating an equivalent Info.plist) and not Java 7 (e.g., using the new Oracle appbundler.jar).

Comment: Oops I forgot about the license. In my case, just to be able to access to some 32-bit native libraries. I am using Java 6. But it is like daemon process in background. My UI is in JavaFX and it communicates with Java 6 process. Java 6 process is launched by `ProcessBuilder`. What to do in such case?

Comment: @Jatin It should work the same way, even though you are using Java as a background process.  In fact, typing "java -version" at the command line is enough to cause it to download it if it is not already installed.

Comment: Thanks :). One last question. Wont typing `java -version` will make it download the latest version and not Java 6?

Comment: @Jatin No, it will only install Apple's latest Java (which is 6), not Oracle's.  A user must manually install Oracle Java 7.  If a user HAS manually installed Oracle Java 7 though, you may have issues -- the `java` command may run 7 instead of 6.  Maybe the safest thing to do would be to create an application bundle for your Java program, even if it is only a background process.  Then at least you could be sure it will use Java 6 or download it if needed.